# Moveit parametically disable one joint

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-melodic, move-group-interface, move-group

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am currently planning the motion of my robot using <move_group_interface.h>. I am aware that I could deactivate one joint in config files (urdf or srdf).
However is there any possibility for instance to exclude the 2. joint for the given motion task. I would like to realize this in a higher level like in the move_group_interface.cpp, because the deactivated joint has to be activated again in different environments.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358995/moveit-parametically-disable-one-joint/) by [xman236](https://answers.ros.org/users/47615/xman236/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2020-08-08

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gates](https://answers.ros.org/users/40632/gates/) on 2021-03-16**:
Can you update if you solved it? I am facing the same issue.

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-03-17**:
Did the current answer not work for you? It looks correct.

**Comment by [Gates](https://answers.ros.org/users/40632/gates/) on 2021-03-17**:
No unfortunately I couldn't make the solution work. Here is my trial after the answer: [constrained move code](https://pastebin.com/KfwDDLd9). I check if I could make the constraints work at lines 50-52-61, I couldn't set. Then I tried (abnormally) attach the constraint to the `goal_pose` yet it didn't work. I don't know how/where to attach the constraints apparently...

**Comment by [Gates](https://answers.ros.org/users/40632/gates/) on 2021-03-17**:
Also I tried attaching the constraint to my group (`arm_group` instead of `goal_pose`) but I get the same error:

```
'MoveGroupCommander' object has no attribute 'motion_plan_request'
```

I tried using `arm_group.set_path_constraints(goal_constraint)`. It sets only path constraints. `arm_group.get_path_constraints()` returns something but `arm_group.get_known_constraints()` returns still nothing.

I don't know how to connect the constraints to my motion plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your goal might be achievable with [Trajectory Constraints](http://docs.ros.org/api/moveit_msgs/html/msg/TrajectoryConstraints.html), especially [Joint Constraints](http://docs.ros.org/api/moveit_msgs/html/msg/JointConstraint.html) which you can [set](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_ros_planning_interface/html/classmoveit_1_1planning__interface_1_1MoveGroupInterface.html#a977cf44d1977f69e5dd95bb3433df79a). [Get your current joint values](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_ros_planning_interface/html/classmoveit_1_1planning__interface_1_1MoveGroupInterface.html#a83676c1aca54429ff0de9919ffb79b7a) and construct the `TrajectoryConstraint` for your disabled joint to stay fixed to that value.

---

Originally posted by [pcoenen](https://answers.ros.org/users/30604/pcoenen/) with karma: 249 on 2020-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1